# How did messenger know what will happen to others?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, revelation, ilm-al-ghaib

According to following Quranic verse  messenger does not know what will happen to him or others in the hereafter

> I am no different from the other messengers, nor do I know what will happen to me or to you. I only follow what is inspired to me. I am no more than a clear warner"
>   [[46:9]](http://tanzil.net/#46:9)

but according to hadiths  messenger knew people who are guaranteed a place in Janna(famous hadith about 10) :

> **AbdurRahman ibn al-Akhnas** said that when he was in the mosque, a man mentioned Ali (may Allah be pleased with him). So Sa'id ibn Zayd got up and said: I bear witness to the Apostle of Allah (peace be upon him) that I heard him say: Ten persons will go to Paradise: The Prophet (peace be upon him) will go to Paradise, Abu Bakr will go to Paradise, Umar will go to Paradise, Uthman will go to Paradise, Ali will go to Paradise, Talhah will go to Paradise: az-Zubayr ibn al-Awwam will go to paradise, Sa'd ibn Malik will go to Paradise, and Abdur Rahman ibn Awf will go to Paradise. If I wish, I can mention the tenth. The People asked: Who is he: So he kept silence. The again asked: Who is he: He replied: He is Sa'id ibn Zayd.
>
> Narrated **Abdur Rahman bin Awf**: that the Messenger of Allah () said:
>   "Abu Bakr is in Paradise, 'Umar is in Paradise, 'Uthman is in
>   Paradise, 'Ali is in Paradise, Talhah is in Paradise, Az-Zubair is in
>   Paradise, 'Abdur Rahman bin Awf is in Paradise, Sa'd bin Abi Waqqas is
>   in Paradise, and Abu 'Ubaidah bin Al-Jarrah is in Paradise."
>
> **Jami At Tirmidhi**
>
> Narrated **Safwan bin Muhriz:**
>
> A man asked Ibn 'Umar, "What have you heard from Allah's Apostle
>   regarding An-Najwa?" He said, "Everyone of you will come close to His
>   Lord Who will screen him from the people and say to him, 'Did you do
>   so-and-so?' He will reply, 'Yes.' Then Allah will say, 'Did you do
>   so-and-so?' He will reply, 'Yes.' So Allah will question him and make
>   him confess, and then Allah will say, 'I screened your sins in the
>   world and forgive them for you today.' "
>   **Volume 9, Book 93, Number 605 Sahih Buckari**

. Isn't this a contradiction of the above Quranic verse?

Comment: I must add the hadith you've posted isn't an authentic narration.  The narrator Abdur Rahman bin al-Akhnas al-Kufi is a unknown narrator.  So this makes the hadith weak and questionable.

Comment: But according to Abu Dawud Sulaymān ibn al-Ashʿath al-Azdi as-Sijistani(Abu Dawud) he is a known narrator. How do you decide which one to accept an which one to discard.

Answer (score 7):

No there is no contradiction, Allah says:

> عَالِمُ الْغَيْبِ فَلَا يُظْهِرُ عَلَىٰ غَيْبِهِ أَحَدًا (26) إِلَّا
>   مَنِ ارْتَضَىٰ مِن رَّسُولٍ فَإِنَّهُ يَسْلُكُ مِن بَيْنِ يَدَيْهِ
>   وَمِنْ خَلْفِهِ رَصَدًا
>
> [He is] Knower of the unseen, and He does not disclose His [knowledge
>   of the] unseen to anyone (26) Except whom He has approved of
>   messengers, and indeed, He sends before each messenger and behind him
>   observers(27)

[Surat Al Jinn](http://quran.com/72/26-27)

Meaning that none, not even the Prophet (peace be upon him) knew anything of the unseen, except for that which was revealed to him.  So **the obvious answer**, even in the verse you mention in your question, is that the knowledge of some of those who will go to paradise was revealed.

> وَمَا يَنطِقُ عَنِ الْهَوَىٰ (3) إِنْ هُوَ إِلَّا وَحْيٌ يُوحَىٰ
>
> Nor does he speak from [his own] inclination. (3) It is not but a
>   revelation revealed (4)

[Suratun Najm](http://quran.com/53/3-4)

Comment: Say, "I do not know if what you are promised is near or if my Lord will grant for it a [long] period."     Surat Al Jinn 25. this doesn't mean what will happen to others.

Comment: @ayub "Except whom He has approved of messengers, and indeed, He sends before each messenger and behind him observers"  Surat Al Jinn 27.  but this does.

Comment: What you are saying is Allah revealed Quran and then gave hidden knowledge which goes against his Quran. Yes Allah can give hidden knowldge to whoever he wills. If you know the story of Moses and wise teacher that teacher given hidden knowledge not Moses. This does not prove Muhammad(PBUH) given hidden knowledge. And there is a Sahih hadith in Buckari narrated by Aisha which says Rasulallah have no hidden knowledge nor he has seen the God .

Comment: @ayub who is talking about hidden knowledge, I know the Prophet had no such thing, what I am saying is that Allah revealed the Quran and Sunnah to the Prophet, as well as some knowledge of the unseen when Allah willed so.  I am definitely not saying that the Prophet had some hidden knowledge, or had full knowledge of the unseen 24 hours every single day of his life.

Comment: please bring forth your proof Allah revealed Quran And Sunnah(hadiths)?. Why Allah promised to protect Quran only.

Comment: @ayub If you have any further questions, then please use the search feature to search this site to find your answer, if you don't then please [ask your question here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  Comments are not meant for extended discussion.